# Jenkins Pipeline docker.withRegistry() push leads to endless loop

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, docker-registry

I managed to setup a jenkins on kubernetes and gitbucket on kubernetes. Now I am trying out to create my own first docker file for uploading on dockerhub. Unfortunately it fails while uploading to docker. Build is successfully, but I cant manage how to upload it to dockerhub (private repository).

**Jenkinsfile**

```groovy
def label = "${BUILD_TAG}"
 
podTemplate(label: label, containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'docker', image: 'docker:latest', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true)
],
volumes: [
    hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock')
]) {
    node(label) {
        def app
        def myRepo = checkout scm
        def gitCommit = myRepo.GIT_COMMIT
        def gitBranch = myRepo.GIT_BRANCH
        def shortGitCommit = "${gitCommit[0..10]}"
        def previousGitCommit = sh(script: "git rev-parse ${gitCommit}~", returnStdout: true)
        
        stage('Decommission Infrastructure') {
            container('kubectl') {
                echo "Decmomission..."
            }
        }
        
        stage('Build application') {
            container('docker') {
                app = docker.build("fasautomation/recon", ".")
            }
        }
        
        stage('Run unit tests') {
            container('docker') {
                app.inside {
                    sh 'echo "Test passed"'
                }
            }
        }

            stage('Docker publish') {
                container('docker') {
                    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', '<<jenkins store-credentials>>') {
                        echo "Pushing 1..."
                        // Push tagged version
                    app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
                    echo "Pushing 2..."
                    // Push latest-tagged version
                    app.push("latest")
                    echo "Pushed!"
                    }
            }
            }
            
            stage('Deployment') {
            container('docker') {
                // Deploy to Kubernetes
                echo 'Deploying'
            }
            }
            
        stage('Provision Infrastructure') {
            container('kubectl') {
                echo 'Provision...'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Jenkins Logs**

```log
[...]
[Pipeline] stage (hide)
[Pipeline] { (Docker publish)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
Executing sh script inside container docker of pod jenkins-recon-master-116-0ksw8-f7779
Executing command: "docker" "login" "-u" "*****" "-p" ******** "https://index.docker.io/v1/" 
exit
<<endless loading symbol>>
```

Does anyone has a clue how to debug here? Credentials work. Not sure why there is the exit in the log without the logs for pushing afterwards... :-(

Comment: Given there appears to be an immediate exit after the login attempt (unless this also involves a failure to flush standard out), the login is probably failing for some reason, and you may want to pursue that angle.

Comment: Any idea why this occurs? Credentials are correct..
Is there any logfile I can check for getting details?

Comment: Can you execute the displayed command as the pipeline user on the agent server?

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard,
not sure how to do so... It's running in a docker container within a pod. Not sure how Jenkins executes the pipeline there. I could connect to the pod via CLI and execute commands within it. But I don't know how to set debug entities to stop script execution and interfer with a cmd there (as I know it from front-end debugging).

Any recommendation?

Comment: I wonder if you found any solution to this issue?

Comment: At least for me, downgrading the version of `docker-commons` from 1.20 to 1.19 Helped.
There seems to be an issue with 1.20 - https://jira.jenkins-ci.linuxfound.info/projects/JENKINS/issues/JENKINS-69436?filter=allopenissues

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check if the issue persists with [Jenkins Docker commons 1.21](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-commons-plugin/releases/tag/docker-commons-1.21)

The [PR 86 "docker login - get password from stdin"](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-commons-plugin/pull/86) was reverted ([PR 108](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-commons-plugin/pull/108)).
And it includes [JENKINS-69436 "Error: cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device"](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-69436).

That means the `docker.withRegistry` step has better chances now (since Aug. 2022 and docker commons 1.21) to execute successfully.